# WSO2 api manager error 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When I try to execute my api through API Console in WSO2 api manager , I received error "404 - File or directory not found".

My API is working fine when I run it through the Postmen tool.
Could you please help me to identify above issue.
Here with attached some screenshots.

[image: WSO2 API Manager]
 [image: Postman]

Comment: Looks like your resource definitions are wrong. Please post a screenshot of that.

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnFgu.png)

Comment: How did you set your backend URL in endpoint section?

Comment: [ backend URL in endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX3Rn.png)

Comment: You have wrongly defined the resource path. If you enabled the http wire logs in <APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/log4j.properties file, you will find the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the gateway URL in the API console and access it from the browser. Then go to advanced add exception.

This will add the server certificate to the browser trust store and console will work afterward.

Comment: The problem seems to be related to resources here.

Comment: Still I have the same error, I have added Request URL to trusted site and also configure correct IP in <ThrottlingConfigurations> section of api-manager.xml.

Comment: Please note my api is in http, is it possible to call from https to http?

Comment: You can't invoke a HTTP endpoint from a HTTPs origin and this is blocked from the browser level due to "Mixed Content".  We don't have a working solution to do the try it other than switching the store to the HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your API context and resources like this.

[image]

Comment: Enable wire logs and update question with logs. http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html